# Programmatically highlight text in MS Word using java

Tags: java, .net, ms-word, highlighting

Can someone tell me if it is possible to highlight certain words (provided by page numbers and line numbers) in a word document (basically DOCX)? My primary choice is to use Java. If there is any .Net solution for this problem, please let me know that.

Thanks.

Comment: A .docx is basically just an xml file inside a zip file, so you can open that up and manually parse the XML if there's no library to do it for you.

Comment: Yes, I have doing so. But, when I opened the XML for the document, I did not find any XML tag to get to a specific page or specific line number. My intention is to go to a specific line number in a specific page and then, highlight the contents of that line.

Comment: Please find stcakoverflow answer which is provided
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419619/how-can-i-set-background-colour-of-a-run-a-word-in-line-or-a-paragraph-in-a-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found in java but in .NET

```
object missObj = Missing.Value;
            object path = @"D:\mydoc.docx";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(ref path, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj, ref missObj);
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range in doc.Words)
            {
                if (range.Text.Trim() == "the text")
                {
                    range.HighlightColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkYellow;
                    range.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdWhite;
                }
            }
```

Source : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/9fba8427-8b3c-44f2-b19f-92eb5108693b/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check it and get back to you then.

Comment: I tried the sample code and it seems that it only highlights a word, not a string. Suppose I provide "the text" as , it will not highlight the string in the document. But, if I provide "text", it highlights. Is there anything else to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible in Java, but you probably need implement this via a 3th libraries, Apache POI is a good choice, which is a Java API for Microsoft Documents, provides almost all functions and features for manipulating DOC or DOCX fromat files.

http://poi.apache.org/

What you meant "highlight" is to paragraph background color and highlight text color?  Or something else?

Comment: I have done some research on Apache POI earlier. But, I did not get any clue on how to do the highlighting. On a high level, I want to do the following - 1) Go to the specified page number, 2) Go to the specified line number, 3) Highlight the line. Is it possible with POI? If it is, can you provide some dummy code?

Comment: I want to highlight a line (words in the line to be more precise) in a specific page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using Apache POI, you can read the Microsoft Word DOC and can do operations on that DOC like highlighting the text, etc.