# How can I set background colour of a run (a word in line or a paragraph) in a docx file by using Apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi, xwpf

I want to create a docx file by using Apache POI.

I want to set background colour of a run (i.e. a word or some parts of a paragraph).

How can I do this?

Is in possible via Apache POI or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34544181/5717099) is a solution for HWPF. I am unsure if the same is possible using XWPF, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Word provides two possibilities for this. There are really background colors possible within runs. But there are also so called highlighting settings.

With `XWPF` both possibilities are only possible using the underlying objects `CTShd` and `CTHighlight`. But while `CTShd` is shipped with the default `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-...jar`, for the `CTHighlight` the fully `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` is needed as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTShd;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STShd;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHighlightColor;
/*
To
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STHighlightColor;
the fully ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar is needed as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025
*/

public class WordRunWithBGColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("This is text with ");

  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("background color");
  CTShd cTShd = run.getCTR().addNewRPr().addNewShd();
  cTShd.setVal(STShd.CLEAR);
  cTShd.setColor("auto");
  cTShd.setFill("00FFFF");

  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText(" and this is ");

  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("highlighted");
  run.getCTR().addNewRPr().addNewHighlight().setVal(STHighlightColor.YELLOW);

  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText(" text.");

  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("WordRunWithBGColor.docx"));

 }
}
```