# How can I set background fill of a run (a word in line or a paragraph) in a docx file by using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I know that it is possible to set the color of the run by: [How can I set background colour of a run (a word in line or a paragraph) in a docx file by using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419619/how-can-i-set-background-colour-of-a-run-a-word-in-line-or-a-paragraph-in-a-do)

The relevant code is for example (see the answer in the referenced question):

```
 XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
 run.setText("background color");
 CTShd cTShd = run.getCTR().addNewRPr().addNewShd();
 cTShd.setVal(STShd.CLEAR);
 cTShd.setColor("auto");
 cTShd.setFill("00FFFF");
```

I would like to use an image instead as a pattern, is it possible? I know that the argument used for the fill argument is an object, so is it possible to use a picture reference or something like that?

I also know how to add directly a picture in a docx document, for example:

```
     Image image = // my image to use
     float widthEMU = // the width of the image in EMU
     float heightEMU = // the height of the image in EMU
     BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage((int) width, (int) height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

     // Draw the image on to the buffered image
     Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
     bGr.drawImage(_image, 0, 0, null);
     bGr.dispose();

     ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     ImageIO.write(bimage, "png", os);
     InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
     XWPFPicture pic = run.addPicture(is, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "Picture", widthEMU, heightEMU);
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no option to set pattern fills or picture fills to character runs in Word. How would you do this using The Word GUI? Apache POI cannot do what Word itself is not able to do.

Comment: There is a way to do that in word, maybe indirectly: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-group-picture-text-in-ms-word You are able to group a text box and an image and put the result anywhere in the document. But I agree that the result is not a simple text run

Comment: To be fait, I really thought when I asked the question that Word was able to directly add a pattern under a text.